# How to extract h3 tag text inside a div with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

100) Reservoir Dogs

I am trying to extract "100) Reservoir Dogs" but it is showing me none or an empty list [].

I have tried multiple methods for eg 'find', 'find_all', 'find_next' 'select' but all failed, Here is the code;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
all_movies = soup.find('h3', class_='jsx-4245974604')
print(all_movies)
```

Answer (score 3):

The data you're looking for is embedded inside `<script>` tag, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it (it doesn't execute JavaScript). To parse the data you can use following example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)

def get_images(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        if o.get('__typename') == 'Image':
            yield o
        else:
            for v in o.values():
                yield from get_images(v)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from get_images(v)

pat = re.compile(r'\d+\)')
out = set()
for i in get_images(data):
    name = i['name']
    if pat.match(name):
        out.add(name)

print(*sorted(out, key=lambda n: int(n.split(')')[0])), sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
1) The Lord Of The Rings: The Fellowship Of The Ring
2) Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back
3) The Godfather
4) The Dark Knight
5) The Shawshank Redemption
6) Jaws
7) Pulp Fiction
8) Avengers: Infinity War
9) Raiders Of The Lost Ark
10) Goodfellas

...and so on.
```